# RUN command cannot access volumes

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api2, .net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

It appears `RUN` in a `dockerfile` can't see my volume directory where `ENTRYPOINT` can.

Here is an example with a `dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` that is having the issue:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk
EXPOSE 5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
WORKDIR /src/testing
RUN dotnet restore
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run", "--urls=http://0.0.0.0:5000"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  doctnetcore-api-project:
    build: ./api/
    container_name: doctnetcore-api-project
    image: doctnetcore-api-project:development
    restart: 'always'
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    volumes:
      - /api/src:/src

networks:
  mywebmc:
    external:
      name: mynetwork
```

When I run `docker-compose up` I get an error shown below:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
ERROR: Service 'doctnetcore-api-project' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

If I comment out `RUN dotnet restore` and run `dotnet restore` manually before running `docker-compose`, it works fine.

So for whatever reason it appears `RUN` can't see my volume directory and `ENTRYPOINT` can see my volume directory.

Comment: Do you expect the volume's contents to be part of the hash used to identify the container, such that when those contents change the `dotnet restore` command is reinvoked? If so, you don't want this to be a volume at all, but want to COPY it in in such a way that it's considered part of the container's state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statements in a Dockerfile are executed at *build-time* (`docker build`) and at this point there are no volumes present.

In contrast, the `ENTRYPOINT` is executed when you *run* a container (`docker run`) which has access to potentially mapped volumes.

Comment: So is there a way I can accomplish this?

Comment: You can add your .NET project to the folder where the Dockerfile is located. This will make it available during the build process.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "this". Do you just want to ensure that `dotnet restore` is invoked before `dotnet run`? Then fold both commands into your ENTRYPOINT and there you are.

Comment: I didn’t realize you could run multiple commands with ENTRYPOINT.